# Random freezing in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: gnome

I have been enjoying a smooth Ubuntu experience until recently.

Just sometimes after using Firefox, it tends to freeze up Firefox, System Monitor and other related apps (even the screenshot took). Yet alt+tab works, the seconds on clock on the activities bar is still moving.

I refreshed my Firefox but it doesn't seem to be working. I mostly only installed updates as recommended by the Software Centre and Synaptic Package Manager only.

The only configuration change I did was the installation of the CPUfreq-gui and adjusting the CPU governor (to ondemand to performance and back) and adjusting the maximum clock to 4200Mhz. Also, I added 2 Gnome extensions to monitor the 1) CPU activity and 2) change the CPU governor as required.

I am using a Ryzen 3600 with a GTX 1660 Super with 32GB RAM.

Any ideas where I can start troubleshooting to resolve this issue?

Thanks guys.

EDIT: I managed to track down the issue and it seems that it was the Gnome Shell. It crashed again on me awhile ago too.

I have attached the syslog:

```
Jun 25 10:37:08 Azrael-PC gnome-shell[13776]: ###!!! [Parent][RunMessage] Error: Channel closing: too late to send/recv, messages will be lost
```

Jun 25 10:40:30 Azrael-PC kernel: [55591.619387] snd_hda_intel 0000:05:00.0: azx_get_response timeout, switching to polling mode: last cmd=0x101f0500
Jun 25 10:40:31 Azrael-PC kernel: [55592.623391] snd_hda_intel 0000:05:00.0: azx_get_response timeout, switching to single_cmd mode: last cmd=0x101f0500
Jun 25 10:40:36 Azrael-PC kernel: [55597.679592] azx_single_send_cmd: 386 callbacks suppressed
Jun 25 10:40:39 Azrael-PC kernel: [55600.120551] snd_hda_intel 0000:05:00.0: Direct firmware load for ctefx-desktop.bin failed with error -2
Jun 25 10:40:41 Azrael-PC kernel: [55602.691591] azx_single_send_cmd: 242 callbacks suppressed
Jun 25 10:40:46 Azrael-PC kernel: [55607.695595] azx_single_send_cmd: 165 callbacks suppressed
Jun 25 10:40:51 Azrael-PC kernel: [55612.699581] azx_single_send_cmd: 165 callbacks suppressed
Jun 25 10:40:56 Azrael-PC kernel: [55617.727584] azx_single_send_cmd: 168 callbacks suppressed
Jun 25 10:40:59 Azrael-PC kernel: [55620.395381] snd_hda_codec_ca0132 hdaudioC0D1: ca0132 DSP load image failed
Jun 25 10:40:59 Azrael-PC kernel: [55620.395622] snd_hda_codec_ca0132 hdaudioC0D1: cannot read sub nodes for FG 0x01
Jun 25 10:40:59 Azrael-PC gnome-shell[14011]: [Child 14011, AudioIPC0] WARNING: 7fcbd4ffbc80 StateCallback() state 0 cubeb error: file /build/firefox-Y52fNi/firefox-89.0.1+build1/dom/media/AudioStream.cpp:654
Jun 25 10:40:59 Azrael-PC gnome-shell[14011]: [Child 14011, MediaDecoderStateMachine #1] WARNING: 7fcbd4ffbc80 OpenCubeb() failed to init cubeb: file /build/firefox-Y52fNi/firefox-89.0.1+build1/dom/media/AudioStream.cpp:323
Jun 25 10:41:01 Azrael-PC kernel: [55622.735591] azx_single_send_cmd: 239 callbacks suppressed
Jun 25 10:41:06 Azrael-PC kernel: [55627.739590] azx_single_send_cmd: 277 callbacks suppressed
Jun 25 10:41:11 Azrael-PC kernel: [55632.763575] azx_single_send_cmd: 256 callbacks suppressed
Jun 25 10:41:13 Azrael-PC kernel: [55634.795810] snd_hda_codec_ca0132 hdaudioC0D1: out of range cmd 1:b:707:ffffff18
Jun 25 10:41:13 Azrael-PC kernel: [55634.796230] snd_hda_codec_ca0132 hdaudioC0D1: out of range cmd 1:10:707:ffffffd8
Jun 25 10:41:16 Azrael-PC kernel: [55637.775599] azx_single_send_cmd: 260 callbacks suppressed
Jun 25 10:41:21 Azrael-PC kernel: [55642.803581] azx_single_send_cmd: 261 callbacks suppressed
Jun 25 10:41:26 Azrael-PC kernel: [55647.807591] azx_single_send_cmd: 301 callbacks suppressed
Jun 25 10:41:29 Azrael-PC gnome-shell[14011]: [Child 14011, AudioIPC0] WARNING: 7fcbd4f22ac0 StateCallback() state 0 cubeb error: file /build/firefox-Y52fNi/firefox-89.0.1+build1/dom/media/AudioStream.cpp:654
Jun 25 10:41:29 Azrael-PC gnome-shell[14011]: [Child 14011, MediaDecoderStateMachine #1] WARNING: 7fcbd4f22ac0 OpenCubeb() failed to init cubeb: file /build/firefox-Y52fNi/firefox-89.0.1+build1/dom/media/AudioStream.cpp:323
Jun 25 10:41:31 Azrael-PC kernel: [55652.831642] azx_single_send_cmd: 265 callbacks suppressed
Jun 25 10:41:36 Azrael-PC kernel: [55657.835583] azx_single_send_cmd: 293 callbacks suppressed
Jun 25 10:41:41 Azrael-PC kernel: [55662.843584] azx_single_send_cmd: 266 callbacks suppressed
Jun 25 10:41:47 Azrael-PC kernel: [55667.855567] azx_single_send_cmd: 298 callbacks suppressed
Jun 25 10:41:52 Azrael-PC kernel: [55672.859591] azx_single_send_cmd: 228 callbacks suppressed
Jun 25 10:41:57 Azrael-PC kernel: [55677.871598] azx_single_send_cmd: 258 callbacks suppressed
Jun 25 10:41:59 Azrael-PC gnome-shell[14011]: [Child 14011, AudioIPC0] WARNING: 7fcbcbeefe40 StateCallback() state 0 cubeb error: file /build/firefox-Y52fNi/firefox-89.0.1+build1/dom/media/AudioStream.cpp:654
Jun 25 10:41:59 Azrael-PC gnome-shell[14011]: [Child 14011, MediaDecoderStateMachine #1] WARNING: 7fcbcbeefe40 OpenCubeb() failed to init cubeb: file /build/firefox-Y52fNi/firefox-89.0.1+build1/dom/media/AudioStream.cpp:323
Jun 25 10:42:02 Azrael-PC kernel: [55682.883590] azx_single_send_cmd: 243 callbacks suppressed
Jun 25 10:42:07 Azrael-PC kernel: [55687.887588] azx_single_send_cmd: 272 callbacks suppressed
Jun 25 10:42:12 Azrael-PC kernel: [55692.891606] azx_single_send_cmd: 287 callbacks suppressed
Jun 25 10:42:17 Azrael-PC kernel: [55697.919593] azx_single_send_cmd: 278 callbacks suppressed
Jun 25 10:42:22 Azrael-PC kernel: [55702.927585] azx_single_send_cmd: 280 callbacks suppressed
Jun 25 10:42:23 Azrael-PC kernel: [55704.431809] snd_hda_codec_ca0132 hdaudioC0D1: out of range cmd 1:7:706:ffffffff
Jun 25 10:42:27 Azrael-PC kernel: [55707.947594] azx_single_send_cmd: 291 callbacks suppressed
Jun 25 10:42:30 Azrael-PC gnome-shell[14011]: [Child 14011, AudioIPC0] WARNING: 7fcbcbea79e0 StateCallback() state 0 cubeb error: file /build/firefox-Y52fNi/firefox-89.0.1+build1/dom/media/AudioStream.cpp:654
Jun 25 10:42:30 Azrael-PC gnome-shell[14011]: [Child 14011, MediaDecoderStateMachine #1] WARNING: 7fcbcbea79e0 OpenCubeb() failed to init cubeb: file /build/firefox-Y52fNi/firefox-89.0.1+build1/dom/media/AudioStream.cpp:323
Jun 25 10:42:30 Azrael-PC gnome-shell[14011]: [Child 14011, MediaDecoderStateMachine #1] WARNING: Decoder=7fcbc5fa4c00 [OnMediaSinkAudioError]: file /build/firefox-Y52fNi/firefox-89.0.1+build1/dom/media/MediaDecoderStateMachine.cpp:3916
Jun 25 10:42:32 Azrael-PC kernel: [55712.959591] azx_single_send_cmd: 254 callbacks suppressed
Jun 25 10:42:37 Azrael-PC kernel: [55717.971587] azx_single_send_cmd: 247 callbacks suppressed
Jun 25 10:42:37 Azrael-PC kernel: [55718.815805] snd_hda_codec_ca0132 hdaudioC0D1: out of range cmd 1:b:707:ffffff18
Jun 25 10:42:37 Azrael-PC kernel: [55718.816014] snd_hda_codec_ca0132 hdaudioC0D1: out of range cmd 1:10:707:ffffffd8
Jun 25 10:42:42 Azrael-PC kernel: [55722.983589] azx_single_send_cmd: 268 callbacks suppressed
Jun 25 10:42:47 Azrael-PC kernel: [55728.003584] azx_single_send_cmd: 299 callbacks suppressed
Jun 25 10:42:52 Azrael-PC kernel: [55733.019588] azx_single_send_cmd: 259 callbacks suppressed
Jun 25 10:42:57 Azrael-PC kernel: [55738.039600] azx_single_send_cmd: 300 callbacks suppressed
Jun 25 10:43:02 Azrael-PC kernel: [55743.051588] azx_single_send_cmd: 257 callbacks suppressed
Jun 25 10:43:07 Azrael-PC kernel: [55748.059586] azx_single_send_cmd: 294 callbacks suppressed
Jun 25 10:43:12 Azrael-PC kernel: [55753.071595] azx_single_send_cmd: 257 callbacks suppressed
Jun 25 10:43:17 Azrael-PC kernel: [55758.075601] azx_single_send_cmd: 291 callbacks suppressed
Jun 25 10:43:22 Azrael-PC kernel: [55763.095593] azx_single_send_cmd: 259 callbacks suppressed
Jun 25 10:43:27 Azrael-PC kernel: [55768.103593] azx_single_send_cmd: 299 callbacks suppressed
Jun 25 10:43:32 Azrael-PC kernel: [55773.119587] azx_single_send_cmd: 265 callbacks suppressed
Jun 25 10:43:37 Azrael-PC kernel: [55778.127596] azx_single_send_cmd: 294 callbacks suppressed
Jun 25 10:43:38 Azrael-PC kernel: [55779.323609] snd_hda_codec_ca0132 hdaudioC0D1: Unable to sync register 0x2b8000. -5
Jun 25 10:47:40 Azrael-PC gnome-shell[2577]: ../clutter/clutter/clutter-actor.c:10558: The clutter_actor_set_allocation() function can only be called from within the implementation of the ClutterActor::allocate() virtual function.
Jun 25 10:47:42 Azrael-PC kernel: [56022.887604] azx_single_send_cmd: 45 callbacks suppressed
Jun 25 10:47:43 Azrael-PC systemd[2329]: Started Application launched by gnome-shell.
Jun 25 10:47:43 Azrael-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2434]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: disconnected
Jun 25 10:47:43 Azrael-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2434]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: Internal DisplayPort
Jun 25 10:47:43 Azrael-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2434]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: 2660.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Jun 25 10:47:43 Azrael-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2434]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Jun 25 10:47:43 Azrael-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2434]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: disconnected
Jun 25 10:47:43 Azrael-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2434]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: Internal TMDS
Jun 25 10:47:43 Azrael-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2434]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Jun 25 10:47:43 Azrael-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2434]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Jun 25 10:47:43 Azrael-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2434]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: disconnected
Jun 25 10:47:43 Azrael-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2434]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: Internal DisplayPort
Jun 25 10:47:43 Azrael-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2434]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: 2660.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Jun 25 10:47:43 Azrael-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2434]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Jun 25 10:47:43 Azrael-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2434]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Philips PHL 240V5A (DFP-3): connected
Jun 25 10:47:43 Azrael-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2434]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Philips PHL 240V5A (DFP-3): Internal TMDS
Jun 25 10:47:43 Azrael-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2434]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Philips PHL 240V5A (DFP-3): 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Jun 25 10:47:43 Azrael-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2434]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Jun 25 10:47:43 Azrael-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2434]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: disconnected
Jun 25 10:47:43 Azrael-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2434]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: Internal TMDS
Jun 25 10:47:43 Azrael-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2434]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Jun 25 10:47:43 Azrael-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2434]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Jun 25 10:47:43 Azrael-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2434]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: disconnected
Jun 25 10:47:43 Azrael-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2434]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: Internal DisplayPort
Jun 25 10:47:43 Azrael-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2434]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: 2660.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Jun 25 10:47:43 Azrael-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2434]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Jun 25 10:47:43 Azrael-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2434]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-6: disconnected
Jun 25 10:47:43 Azrael-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2434]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-6: Internal TMDS
Jun 25 10:47:43 Azrael-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2434]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-6: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Jun 25 10:47:43 Azrael-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2434]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Jun 25 10:47:47 Azrael-PC kernel: [56027.903592] azx_single_send_cmd: 581 callbacks suppressed
Jun 25 10:47:50 Azrael-PC kernel: [56031.675787] snd_hda_codec_ca0132 hdaudioC0D1: cannot read sub nodes for FG 0x01
Jun 25 10:47:52 Azrael-PC kernel: [56032.915606] azx_single_send_cmd: 298 callbacks suppressed
Jun 25 10:47:57 Azrael-PC kernel: [56037.923594] azx_single_send_cmd: 252 callbacks suppressed
Jun 25 10:48:02 Azrael-PC kernel: [56042.927615] azx_single_send_cmd: 301 callbacks suppressed
Jun 25 10:48:05 Azrael-PC kernel: [56046.139813] snd_hda_codec_ca0132 hdaudioC0D1: out of range cmd 1:b:707:ffffff18
Jun 25 10:48:05 Azrael-PC kernel: [56046.140233] snd_hda_codec_ca0132 hdaudioC0D1: out of range cmd 1:10:707:ffffffd8
Jun 25 10:48:07 Azrael-PC kernel: [56047.951587] azx_single_send_cmd: 223 callbacks suppressed
Jun 25 10:48:12 Azrael-PC kernel: [56052.959609] azx_single_send_cmd: 295 callbacks suppressed
Jun 25 10:48:17 Azrael-PC kernel: [56057.971613] azx_single_send_cmd: 266 callbacks suppressed
Jun 25 10:48:20 Azrael-PC systemd[2329]: Started Application launched by gnome-shell.
Jun 25 10:48:22 Azrael-PC kernel: [56062.983596] azx_single_send_cmd: 295 callbacks suppressed
Jun 25 10:48:27 Azrael-PC kernel: [56068.011583] azx_single_send_cmd: 276 callbacks suppressed
Jun 25 10:48:32 Azrael-PC kernel: [56073.023579] azx_single_send_cmd: 288 callbacks suppressed
Jun 25 10:48:36 Azrael-PC gnome-shell[14011]: [Child 14011, AudioIPC0] WARNING: 7fcbd2202ba0 StateCallback() state 0 cubeb error: file /build/firefox-Y52fNi/firefox-89.0.1+build1/dom/media/AudioStream.cpp:654
Jun 25 10:48:36 Azrael-PC gnome-shell[14011]: [Child 14011, MediaDecoderStateMachine #1] WARNING: 7fcbd2202ba0 OpenCubeb() failed to init cubeb: file /build/firefox-Y52fNi/firefox-89.0.1+build1/dom/media/AudioStream.cpp:323
Jun 25 10:48:37 Azrael-PC kernel: [56078.035594] azx_single_send_cmd: 277 callbacks suppressed
Jun 25 10:48:42 Azrael-PC kernel: [56083.059591] azx_single_send_cmd: 265 callbacks suppressed
Jun 25 10:48:46 Azrael-PC gnome-shell[13776]: ###!!! [Parent][RunMessage] Error: Channel closing: too late to send/recv, messages will be lost
Jun 25 10:48:46 Azrael-PC systemd[2329]: gnome-launched-firefox.desktop-13776.scope: Succeeded.
Jun 25 10:48:47 Azrael-PC kernel: [56088.071614] azx_single_send_cmd: 238 callbacks suppressed
Jun 25 10:48:52 Azrael-PC kernel: [56093.075605] azx_single_send_cmd: 244 callbacks suppressed
Jun 25 10:48:57 Azrael-PC kernel: [56098.083615] azx_single_send_cmd: 286 callbacks suppressed
Jun 25 10:49:02 Azrael-PC kernel: [56103.091765] azx_single_send_cmd: 291 callbacks suppressed
Jun 25 10:49:07 Azrael-PC kernel: [56108.103617] azx_single_send_cmd: 283 callbacks suppressed
Jun 25 10:49:12 Azrael-PC kernel: [56113.131614] azx_single_send_cmd: 294 callbacks suppressed
Jun 25 10:49:13 Azrael-PC systemd[2329]: Started Application launched by gsd-media-keys.
Jun 25 10:49:14 Azrael-PC kernel: [56115.763821] snd_hda_codec_ca0132 hdaudioC0D1: out of range cmd 1:7:706:ffffffff
Jun 25 10:49:14 Azrael-PC kernel: [56115.764851] snd_hda_codec_ca0132 hdaudioC0D1: Unable to sync register 0x2b8000. -5
Jun 25 10:49:14 Azrael-PC pulseaudio[2339]: Failed to set switch of 'Surround': Input/output error
Jun 25 10:49:15 Azrael-PC gsd-media-keys[60559]: Select the window whose client you wish to kill with button 1....
Jun 25 10:49:15 Azrael-PC gsd-media-keys[60559]: xkill:  killing creator of resource 0x4e019a0
Jun 25 10:49:15 Azrael-PC systemd[2329]: gnome-launched-xkill-60559.scope: Succeeded.
Jun 25 10:49:17 Azrael-PC systemd[2329]: gnome-launched-gnome-system-monitor.desktop-5482.scope: Succeeded.
Jun 25 10:49:17 Azrael-PC kernel: [56118.135612] azx_single_send_cmd: 294 callbacks suppressed
Jun 25 10:49:18 Azrael-PC systemd[2329]: gnome-launched-firefox.desktop-60416.scope: Succeeded.
Jun 25 10:49:22 Azrael-PC kernel: [56123.159615] azx_single_send_cmd: 293 callbacks suppressed
Jun 25 10:49:24 Azrael-PC systemd[2329]: Started Application launched by gnome-shell.
Jun 25 10:49:25 Azrael-PC rtkit-daemon[1663]: Supervising 8 threads of 2 processes of 2 users.
Jun 25 10:49:25 Azrael-PC rtkit-daemon[1663]: message repeated 5 times: [ Supervising 8 threads of 2 processes of 2 users.]
Jun 25 10:49:25 Azrael-PC rtkit-daemon[1663]: Successfully made thread 60670 of process 60567 owned by '1000' RT at priority 10.
Jun 25 10:49:25 Azrael-PC rtkit-daemon[1663]: Supervising 9 threads of 3 processes of 2 users.
Jun 25 10:49:27 Azrael-PC pulseaudio[2339]: snd_pcm_avail() returned a value that is exceptionally large: 2479512 bytes (14056 ms).
Jun 25 10:49:27 Azrael-PC pulseaudio[2339]: Most likely this is a bug in the ALSA driver 'snd_hda_intel'. Please report this issue to the ALSA developers.

Comment: Try another browser. If the problem persists, it's probably due to CPU tweaks that you've made.

Comment: Undo your changes, one at a time, until the problem goes away.

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys. I was wondering is there a way to reset CPU tweaks to default settings? I doubt it is Firefox because it was working great before.

Comment: I found more information from a recent crash:
A couple of things:
gnome-shell[13776]: ###!!! [Parent][RunMessage] Error: Channel closing: too late to send/recv, messages will be lost
kernel: [55600.120551] snd_hda_intel 0000:05:00.0: Direct firmware load for ctefx-desktop.bin failed with error -2
pulseaudio[2339]: snd_pcm_avail() returned a value that is exceptionally large: 2479512 bytes (14056 ms).
pulseaudio[2339]: Most likely this is a bug in the ALSA driver 'snd_hda_intel'. Please report this issue to the ALSA developers.